# issues with populated dropdown data from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, drop-down-menu

i successfully gather data from json and embedded in my dropdown list, however, sometimes the data didnt load into my dropdown. it append to another dropdown (same class, same data, different id). When I fastly clicked many times the add row button (will add row with the dropdown), the data will not be populated at all. it shows empty dropdown.

```
function getEprIdList() {
var url, listData;
url = 'http://localhost:41251/api/GetEpridList';

$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    $(data).each(function () {

        //prolist is the td that contain the dropdown
        $("#ProList" + countE).empty();
        countE = 0;
        option = $("<option></option>");
        option.val(this.epridName);
        option.append(this.epridName);

        //This to set which Project
        //.pro is class of the select dropdown
        $('.pro').each(function () {
            parentName = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
            var parent = $(this).closest('table');

            $(data).each(function () {
                $("#ProList" + countE, parent).append(option);
                countE++;
            })
        });
    });
    return false;
});
}
```

can anyone please tell me what i do wrong in this code? Thanks

*The dropdown existed in dynamic table, if we add row, then we will add new row with dropdown. the  have dynamic id.

*i add row that contain the dropdown in this code

```
function addtask(element) {

    var name = $(element).closest('tbody').attr('id');
    var tb = document.getElementById(name);

    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.setAttribute("id", "Task1");
    tr.setAttribute("class", "val");
    tb.appendChild(tr);

    // Add item in Task Row
    var cell = tr.insertCell(0);
    cell.innerHTML = "<select id=\"taskDdown" + taskCnt + "\" class=\"task\" name=\"taskName\"><option value=\"\" disabled selected hidden>Select Activity</option></select>" +
    "<span style=\"color:#333333;\" class=\"icon-grommet-trash icon\" onclick=\"deletetask(this)\"/>";

    //Array for Days
    var day = ['null', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'ToT'];

    for (i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        var cell = tr.insertCell(i);
        for (d = 1; d < day.length; d++) {
            var dt = day[i];
            cell.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"" + dt + "\" onkeypress=\"return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57\" class=\"a hour focus\" onchange=\"deci(this)\" value=\"0.00\">";
        }
    }
    var c9 = tr.insertCell(8);
    c9.setAttribute("class", "tot");
    c9.setAttribute("name", "taskTotHour");
    c9.innerHTML = "0.00";

    $(".focus").on("click", function () {
        $(this).select();
    });

    getTaskList();
}
```

Comment: you have too many loops here. Logic doesn't make sense

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but if i dont loop, then how i can get data from json and embedded in the dropdown? please help...

Comment: well you sure don't need to loop `data` twice and in fact you loop over it numerous times depending on how many ` $('.pro')`there are

Comment: Make your options in one loop....close that loop, then insert them and get rid of the other loop inside `$('.pro').each`

Comment: If each row has it's own dropdown, then the code will cause issue, inserting in wrong places. How do you append/create a new `<tr/>` row to the table and how/when is the `getEprIdList()`  called ?

Comment: I tried, but dropdown will be empty... can you show me the right way to code it?

Comment: i add row through javascript, and everytime button + (add row) clicked, the geteprid function will be called, before inserting the row

Comment: Please guys, help :'( i tried what u suggest but still failed. the data wont come out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to add a row and also the related dropdown next to it. This sample here creates the row and also the corresponding dropdown and then appends it to the table. You can expand on the tr, select attributes as much as needed this is just skeletal structure.

```js
 function addRow() {

   var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

   $.ajax({
     url: root,
     method: 'GET'
   }).then(function(data) {

     var select = $('<select/>');//new select
     var tr = $('<tr/>') // new row
     //add all options from your api
     $.each(data, function(i, item) {
       var option = $('<option/>').val(item.email).text(item.email);
       $(select).append(option); //append option to the select element
     })
     $(tr).append(select);//append the select item to th row
     $('#abc').append(tr);//append the new row to the table
   });
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="abc">


</table>
<input type='button' value="add" onclick="addRow()" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Silly me :) Your code is very great and you just saved my life. Thanks a lot master :)